# A query that shows latest published books from each publisher from a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to write a query that show latest published books from each publisher from a table like this

| bookcode | Name | Publisher | PublishYr |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 61523 | c++ | Pearson | 2018 |
| 54681 | python | sybex | 2017 |
| 45168 | sql | RELX | 2019 |
| 79137 | c# | Macmillan | 2016 |
| 89451 | ccna | Pearson | 2020 |
| 45187 | lpic 1 | RELX | 2021 |
| 16497 | ccnp | sybex | 2018 |
| 19437 | lpic 2 | Penguin | 2019 |

and desired table in query should be:

| Publisher | name |
| --- | --- |
| Pearson | ccna |
| sybex | ccnp |
| RELX | lpic 1 |
| Macmillan | c# |
| Penguin | lpic 2 |

Comment: @JohnL agreed, but you probably should stick to "they" rather than assuming the pronoun "he".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get maximum year per publisher as subquery and join with source table.

```
Select tablename.Publisher, tablename.Name
From tablename
Inner Join (
    Select max(PublishYr) As MaxPublishYr, Publisher
    From tablename 
    Group By Publisher
) as Subqry on Subqry.Publisher = tablename.Publisher
    and Subqry.MaxPublishYr = tablename.PublishYr
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way using window functions:

```
select * from (
   select * , row_number() over (partition by publisher order by PublishYr desc) rn
   from tablename
) t where rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

The query doesn't need a subquery if you use `SELECT TOP(1) WITH TIES`.

```
select top(1) with ties publisher, book_name, 
                   row_number() over (partition by Publisher 
                                      order by PublishYr desc) rn
from TableWithData
order by rn;
```

Comment: Cool idea but this way will require *two* sorts which is likely not going to perform as well, sadly.